# Vertex Colourings for Directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

My question is this;

Show that $\chi (G) \leq k$ if and only if the edges of G can be oriented in such a way that no directed path contains more than k vertices.

(Hint: To prove the backward direction, delete a set of edges of minimum size that destroys all the directed cycles. Let H be the directed subgraph of G obtained in this way. Colour a vertex x with $i \leq k$ if the longest directed path in H which starts in x has I vertices. Show that this has a proper colouring of G.)

I have no idea of where to start!

Kindest regards

Comment: what is a proper coloring in a directed graph?

Comment: a colouring is proper if no two adjacent vertices have the same colour although I cannot see why the definition would be specific in a directed graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the graph can be colored with colors $1,2\dots m$ with $m\leq k$. Direct the graph so that a every edge goes from the smaller color to the larger color. Clearly no directed path with more than $m$ vertices can exist, as the colors are increasing along each path. So the forward implication is trivial.

The backwards implication is the hard one, the idea has a flavor similar to the proof of the Erdös-Szekeres theorem. Suppose that the graph can be directed in such a way that no path contains more than $k$ vertices, we are going to color it using colors $1,2,\dots, k$. Let $H$ be a graph obtained from $G$ by removing an edge set of minimum size.

We now color vertex $v$ with the length of the longest path in $H$ ending with $v$ (which is of course at most $k$). Clearly no two vertices of the same color can be joined by an edge in $H$, Suppose that an edge in $H$ from $u$ to $v$ exists, let $x_1,x_2,\dots,u$ be the longest path in $H$ ending in $u$, then either $x_1,x_2,\dots ,u,v$ is a longer path in $H$ ending in $v$ or it contains repeated vertices and thus a directed cycle.

So now suppose that there is an edge in $G\setminus H$ going from $u$ to $v$ such that $u$ and $v$ have the same color, there must be a directed cycle that uses $uv$ and no other vertex from $G\setminus H$ (because the set of removed edges is of minimum size). Let $u,v,x_1,\dots ,x_nu$ be the cycle, Let $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n,v$ be the longest path in $H$ ending in $v$, then either $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n,v,x_1,\dots,u$ is a longer path in $H$ ending in $v$ or it contains repeated vertices and thus a directed cycle.

Comment: thank you so much! When you say smaller colour to larger colour do you mean in terms of the number or do you mean the number of vertices in that colour?

Comment: in terms of the number.

Comment: In the last paragraph, I am not too sure how u and v can have an edge between them and have the same colour?